# fork() cause msgsnd() invalid argument

Tags: c, fork, ipc

I'm trying to implement a program that simulate Chinese Morra beetween processes. I have three of them: two Players and a Judge. By far I'm stuck with the latter because when creating a child process, the `fork()` cause a simple `msgsnd()` to fail, showing `Invalid Argument`.
What am I missing here?

```
#define DIM_MSG 1024

#define SEND_REQUEST 1

typedef struct {
    long mtype;
    char mtext[DIM_MSG];
} msg;

void judge(int queue){
    
    msg message;
    
    strcpy(message.mtext,"request");
   message.mtype = 1;

    if(msgsnd(queue,&message,sizeof(message)-sizeof(long),0) == -1){
        perror("error in send");
        exit(1);
    }
   
    printf("sending stuff\n");

    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int sd_queue;
    
    key_t key = 40;
  
    if((sd_queue = msgget(key,IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1){
        perror("msgget");
        exit(1);
    }
     pid_t pid;

     pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        judge(sd_queue);
    }
    
    msgctl(sd_queue,IPC_RMID,NULL);
}`
```

Comment: Is that not because the parent process deleted the queue?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to put a waitpid() call right before the msgctl().